# Background audio stops when suspending in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have a app that will play a internet mp3 stream written in HTML/JS for Windows 8.

I want it to keep playing the audio even when the app is in the background, however, it still does not work.

I have tried the following

- Added msAudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" to my audio tag
- Added audio as background task in declaration
- I have added the playpausetogglepressed, playpressed, stoppressed, and pausepressed eventlisteners to mediacontrols

```
    mediaControl = Windows.Media.MediaControl;

    // Add event listeners for PBM notifications to illustrate app is
    // getting a new SoundLevel and pass the audio tag along to the function

    mediaControl.addEventListener("soundlevelchanged", $scope.soundLevelChanged, false);

    // Add event listeners for the mandatory media commands.
    // These are necessary to play streams of type 'backgroundCapableMedia'
    mediaControl.addEventListener("playpausetogglepressed", $scope.playpause, false);
    mediaControl.addEventListener("playpressed", $scope.play, false);
    mediaControl.addEventListener("stoppressed", $scope.stop, false);
    mediaControl.addEventListener("pausepressed", $scope.pause, false);
```

I still can't seem to figure out what I've missed.

Comment: Does it work if you just set the source to be an embedded or local file?

Comment: My guess is the background task should be in a different component, i.e., a Windows Runtime Component.

Comment: Two questions--first, have you tried the Playback Manager msAudioCategory sample, and does it do background audio properly? Also, are you on Windows 8 or using Windows 8.1? I ask because there was a breaking change for 8.1 to use Windows.Media.SystemMediaTransportControls instead of Windows.Media.MediaControl. You can see the changes in the 8.1 version of the aforementioned sample.